# React/Rails Redirect Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, cors

I'm building an app with a React front end and a Rails backend.  On a billing page the user will click a button to redirect them to Stripe's Customer Portal.  To make that customer portal session, I need to pass in a customer_id value in the url, which is generated with a stripe gem method.

In my React function, when a button is clicked I run an axios call that hits a rails controller method that finds the customer_id value, calls stripe and fetches the customer portal session.  The controller then ends the method with a redirect to this newly created url and I get the following error in the console:

***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://billing.stripe.com/p/session/test_customer_portal_link' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/customer_portal') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***

The link generated DOES work ok if I copy and paste it into its own browser window.

Here's my Rails controller where I attempt the redirect.

```
class CustomerPortalController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @company_profile = @user.company_profile
    @customer_id = @company_profile.customer_id

    session = Stripe::BillingPortal::Session.create({
        customer: @customer_id
    })
    redirect_to session.url, allow_other_hosts: true, status: :see_other
    return
  end

end
```

and here's the React function where I make the axios call:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { authToken } from 'Helpers/authToken';

function ManageSubscription(){

  const url = '/customer_portal';

  const handlePortal = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post(url, {headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': authToken, Accept: 'application/json' }})
  }

  return(
    <div className="subscription-top-wrapper">
      <div className="customer-portal-row">
        <button 
          onClick={handlePortal}
          className="button-33 w-button"
        >
          Manage Your Subscription
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the rails stack trace, it seems to be working ok:

```
↳ app/controllers/customer_portal_controller.rb:7
Redirected to https://billing.stripe.com/p/session/test_customer_specific_link
Completed 303 See Other in 786ms (ActiveRecord: 27.4ms)
```

ADDING rack-cors info:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             expose: ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
             methods: %i[get post options delete put]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that get stuck on this, I tried a different React based approach.  In my rails controller, instead of attempting the redirect there, I used the controller to pass the url to the front end:

```
render json: { customer_id: session.url }
```

Then in my react function, I take that url and set it to the window location:

```
  const handlePortal = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setDisableButton(true);
    
    axios.post(url, 
    {
      headers: { 
      'X-CSRF-Token': authToken(), 
      Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(({ data }) => {
      const redirectUrl = data.customer_id.toString();
      if (redirectUrl != null) {
        window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      if (typeof onError === 'function') {
        onError(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

It's not the approach I preferred, but it works fine nonetheless.